# javascript not getting value

Tags: javascript, forms, input, alert

I am wondering just how come the following is giving me hassle, it looks straight forward but I am not sure whats happening.

So I have a input box and I want a user to fill it in, every time i run the following

i get unidentified and I am not sure why.

```
<input type="numbers" name="price" class="sell" placeholder="$0.00">
```

Am using the following javascript

```
var price = document.getElementsByName("price")
    alert(price.value);
```

Comment: keep habit of using `document.getElementById("id")`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var price = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
    alert(price.value);
```

document.getElementsByName will give you HTMLCollection (kind of array) as a return type. This is because a number of elements in your dom may share the same name. So if you have number of checkboxes having same name you can refere each checkbox with the array index.

Comment: The return type isn't an array, it is an HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 4):

You have several problems.

The one causing your problem is that [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection) (which is like an array), not a single element. You need to pull the first item off it before trying to access its properties.

```
var price = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
```

Second, `numbers` it not a type of input. [`number` (singular)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-type-number) is.

Third, if you give the example `$0.00` then you are informing people that you expect them to type a value starting with a `$` sign. You can't have a `$` sign in a number.

Comment: Yes I knew that one, we remove the $ after the user clocks the link, we turn the $100.00 Into cents 10000

Comment: @RussellHarrower — If you have a `type="number"` (and the browser supports it) then the browser **will not allow the user to type a $ character** so the placeholder data should not suggest that they should.